# Openpyxl-generated workbook rejected by external parser unless opened and resaved in Excel (with no changes made)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using Amazon's product-listing-creation templates to create & update product listings on Amazon. Amazon's templates include Excel macros to import the contents of a CSV to the template, but I would prefer to bypass this step and clone, edit, and resave the template Excel file directly.

I've got openpyxl code that opens the template, fills in the cells, and saves a new copy with the filled information. I've had to edit the template provided by Amazon in order to allow openpyxl to read the file; I've copied each sheet from the original .xlsm template into a blank workbook and saved it as .xlsx. Except for the errors I'll detail in a minute, this file is still able to be processed by Amazon, so I don't think the format change is (entirely) to blame.

Here's the code that writes the output files:

```
def create_workbook(chunk, file_count):
    '''This creates a single output workbook from a chunk of campaign_dicts.'''
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(AMAZON_TEMPLATE_FILENAME)
    sheet = workbook["Template"]

    rows = []
    for campaign_dict in chunk:
        rows += create_rows(campaign_dict) # Returns a list of lists of cell values.

    write_rows_to_sheet(sheet, rows, TEMPLATE_DATA_STARTING_ROW, TEMPLATE_DATA_STARTING_COL)
    workbook.save("output/output" + str(file_count) + ".xlsx")

def write_rows_to_sheet(sheet, rows, starting_row, starting_col):
    '''This writes data to a worksheet of an openpyxl workbook, starting from the given coordinates.
    The rows for this function should be a list of lists, where each list is a row.'''
    for row_number, row in enumerate(rows):
        for column_number, cell in enumerate(row):
            if isinstance(cell, str):
                cell = re.sub(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE, '', cell)
            sheet.cell(row = row_number + starting_row + 1, column = column_number + starting_col + 1).value = cell
    return sheet
```

The problem is, when I try to upload any file generated by this code to Amazon for processing, it gets rejected with the following Processing Report:

```
Feed Processing Summary:
  Number of records processed       0
  Number of records successful      0

original-record-number  sku error-code  error-type  error-message
0                           99217       Info        The processing report is too long, or has generated too many errors for it to display properly in the Excel sheet. So we have generated the processing report in Text format. The Excel reports are limited to 50,000 errors and 1,000,000 rows of product data.
0                           90502       Fatal       The file does not contain a worksheet with a template type that is supported for Excel upload. Please save your file in a tab-delimited text file format (*.txt) and upload again.
```

What I've found as a workaround is to open the output file in Excel and immediately save it, without making any changes to the file or its data whatsoever. I can't post the actual before & after files (proprietary information), but I know that the file definitely changes before and after the resave, despite the fact that I didn't make any changes when resaving the file; it's just open-resave-close. Note that Excel does not complain whatsoever about the content of the file when I open & resave it.

What's causing this to happen, and how can I fix it in the code so that I don't have this intermediate step?

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the library then please submit a bug report.

Comment: I'm not accusing the library of any bugs at this time; right now I believe there's an error or deficiency in my code. If the consensus arises that it's a bug in the library, then I will indeed file a report.